# How to place the footer on the bottom of

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the footer on the bottom of the page after scrolling. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]

`.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DingDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-images/style-signup.css" >
</head>
<body>
  <p id="logo"><img src="css-images/dingdog-logo.png"></p>
  <ul class="backbutton">
    <li id ="BACK"><a href="">BACK</a></li>
  </ul>


  <footer>

    <img src="social/instagram.png" />
    <img src="social/twitter-white-logo.png" />
    <img src="social/facebook.png" />
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

`css` file

```
footer{
  bottom: 0px;
  right:0px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}

footer img{
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

The second question is. I would like to have some text also on the left of the footer, but do not know how to make it.

I highly appreciate for every help.

Comment: @ritaj i do not want to have a sticky footer. I just want to scroll down and then see it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to position absolute your footer if you want to set it's position using top, bottom, left and right.

```css
footer{
  position: absolute; /*here it is*/
  bottom: 0px;
  right:0px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: did not work...

Comment: Oh sorry, It have to be position fixed, i missed you needed it while scrolling...